# Things get displayed differently on a pane

Tags: java, swing

I display everything raw off the frame. But if I create a `JPanel`) and add the contents to that, then add the panel to the frame using `frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);` but its displayed differently and isnt put properly.

For example normally raw everything is displayed properly. On a pane Text isn't displayed properly from a `JTextPane`, the start is cut off and it doesn't take up the whole window.

And when I add a `JTextBox` to the `mainPane`, it doesn't take the whole width of the window and is put at the half way line when i specifically put `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, also the text box looks like this [] and you can't type in it.

Here is code for start:

```
public class ConsoleApp {

public static  JFrame frame;
public static  JTextPane consoleOutput;
public static JTextField consoleInput;
public JScrollPane scroll;

public static JTabbedPane tabs;

public static JPanel mainPane;
public static JPanel backupPane;

public static InputStream commandInput;

public static StyledDocument doc;

public static boolean trace = false;
public boolean debug = false;

public  Font consoleFont = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12);
//public  Color consoleColour = new Color(50, 50, 50);
public  Color consoleColour = new Color(255, 255, 255);

//public  Logger internalConsole;

public void start()
{

    try {

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

    } catch(Exception e)
    {



    }

    initializeFrame();

}


public void initializeFrame()
{

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("sebagius7110's Minecraft Server Wrapper");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);


    consoleOutput = new JTextPane();
    consoleOutput.setEditable(false);
    consoleOutput.setFont(consoleFont);
    consoleOutput.setBorder(null);
    consoleOutput.setOpaque(false);

    doc = consoleOutput.getStyledDocument();

    consoleInput = new JTextField();
    consoleInput.setFont(consoleFont);
    //consoleInput.setBorder(null);
    consoleInput.setOpaque(false);
    consoleInput.setEditable(true);
    Property.readProperties();
    consoleInput.setCaret(new ConsoleCaret());







    consoleInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            String text = consoleInput.getText();

            if(text.length() >= 1)
            {
                if(text.startsWith("."))
                {

                    onCommand(text);

                } else {

                try{
                      InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(consoleInput.getText().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));


                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                     String input;

                     //input = br.readLine();

                     while(Util.ServerRunning && (input=br.readLine())!=null){
                        Stream.PutString(input);
                     }

                     br.close();

                  }catch(IOException io){
                     io.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }

                consoleInput.selectAll();

            }

        }

    });

    consoleInput.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}

    });

    scroll = new JScrollPane(consoleOutput);
    scroll.setBorder(null);
    scroll.setOpaque(false);
    scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    scroll.setBackground(GetPropValues.cbcolor);

    tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    mainPane = new JPanel();
    backupPane = new JPanel();

    //frame.setUndecorated(true);

    tabs.addTab("Main", mainPane);
    tabs.addTab("Backup", backupPane);

    mainPane.setBorder(null);
    mainPane.setOpaque(false);

    mainPane.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPane.add(consoleInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setContentPane(mainPane);

    //frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //frame.add(consoleInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setSize(660, 350);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

That isn't the whole class, just some of it, so the brackets are not giving errors.

Comment: You add `scroll` and `consoleInput` to `mainPane`, which is added to `tabs`, but which then you set as the content for the window??

Comment: Oh, and `mainPane` is using a `FlowLayout`...

Comment: Try changing `mainPane = new JPanel();` to `mainPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());`; changing `consoleInput = new JTextField();` to `consoleInput = new JTextField(10);`

Comment: Oh, and I'd probably consider using a `JTextArea` over a `JTextPane` for this

Comment: Also i only added content pane not long ago

Comment: I wasnt using the tab right now

Comment: I kind of think you meant to add the `JTabbedPane` to the frame, not the `mainPane`

Comment: I know also thanks u fixed my problems

Comment: But the background is white do i need to change the opacity

Comment: Have you changed the background color of the `mainPane`?

Comment: Sorry ur idea worked i was talking about opaque

Comment: Either make `mainPanel` opaque and set it's background color OR set the `scrollPane` opaque as you're setting it's background color

Answer (score 0):

To set window size with position for any swing component use :

eg.  `compVariable.setBounds(x,y,width,height);`

Comment: Or just use `pack` and `setLocationRelativeTo` which is by far simpler and has better cross platform support